# How to sort a collection filled with objects in a descending order by objects state?

Tags: java

The input is:

- asd 43 asdf asd 43
- 434 asdf
- kasdf asdf stop asdf
- stop

The output should be:

- asdf : 4
- 43 : 2
- asd : 2
- 434 : 1
- kasdf : 1
- stop : 1

On a line "stop" it should stop

I have this class:

```
public class Word implements Comparable<Word> {

    private String content;
    private int frequency;

    public Word(String content) {
        this.content = content;
        this.frequency = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Word o) {
        return this.frequency - o.frequency;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + content  + " : " + frequency;
    }
}
```

The second class Wordcontainer should have all the functionality:

```
public class WordContainer {
    static List<Word> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = null;


        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S+");

        while (!(line = reader.readLine()).equals("stop")) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            while (m.find()) {
                addon(new Word(m.group()));
            
            }
        }

        public static void addon(Word word) {
            for (Word w : list) {
                if (w.getContent().equals(word.getContent())) {
                    w.setFrequency(w.getFrequency() + 1);
            }
        }
        list.add(word);
    }
}
```

How do I fill this list with objects new Word so that the frequencies are in a descending order? Right now I get

- asdf : 4
- asdf : 3
- 43 : 2
- asd : 2
- asdf : 2
- 43 : 1
- 434 : 1
- asd : 1
- asdf : 1
- kasdf : 1
- stop : 1

Comment: `asdf` appears 4 times.

Comment: You use `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: Note that `return this.frequency - o.frequency;` is an incorrect and buggy implementation. It behaves wrong for underflows. Instead, just `return Integer.compare(frequency, o.frequency);`, simple, compact, readable and most important: its correct.

Comment: Each bullet of input, is an object?

Comment: And what do you mean, in descending order, by object state? What is object state?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos yes, every word is an object. In descdending order means by "frequency" field

Comment: using collection to sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in your code, can be fixed by modifying just the `addon` method.

```
public static void addon(Word word) {
    list.stream()
        .filter(w -> w.getContent().equals(word.getContent()))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresentOrElse(w -> w.setFrequency(w.getFrequency()+1), () -> list.add(word));
}
```

You were adding the word to the list, even if the frequency is matched/increased.

**Output:**

```
asdf : 4
asd : 2 
43 : 2
434 : 1
kasdf : 1
stop : 1
```